# Accidentally deleted PyCharm venv folder and code not running

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, python-venv

I accidentally deleted my pycharm projects `venv` foler so I copied all my code files to a new Pycharm project. I'm using Kivy and thats where the error occurs

I did all this but when I tried running my app (in Kivy) I get an error ending in PIL so I pip install Pillow. I run it again and now im getting this error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: dlopen(/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/png
  Referenced from: /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/.dylibs/SDL2_ttf
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/../../.dylibs/png: cannot load 'png' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/.dylibs/png: cannot load 'png' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: dlopen(/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/text/_text_sdl2.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/png
  Referenced from: /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/.dylibs/SDL2_ttf
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/text/../../.dylibs/png: cannot load 'png' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/.dylibs/png: cannot load 'png' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ImportError: dlopen(/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libXau.6.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libxcb.1.1.0.dylib
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXau.6.0.0.dylib: cannot load 'libXau.6.0.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
    /Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libXau.6.0.0.dylib: cannot load 'libXau.6.0.0.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
  File "/Users/drayeshahakim/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 84, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Comment: 15 people have viewed this post, if theres a problem with my post please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Posts in _StackOverflow_ are answered in conjunction with time availability and knowledge on the issue posted. I would not complain that the problem is not solved after X people having read it, because, there simply might not be enough time or background knowledge for it to be solved. 

Your problem might have something to do with a library or something else having been deleted by mistake. Have you just deleted `.venv` or have you deleted something more?

Comment: Did you paste the error messages into your favorite search engine? Did you try to install your dependencies or recreate the venvs? Do you have a list of your dependencies, like a requirements.txt? Did you install kivy and such? Help us help you; check [ask].

Comment: @Robert Yes! I've searched it and have tried everything but just nothing works. I reinstalled everything in my code and as you can see, the error is from Kivy itself. I wasn't getting these errors before in my original PyCharm project

Comment: @YannisP. No, I just deleted PyCharms ```venv``` folder and now I'm trying to get everything working on a new PyCharm project